# python 3.2 installed, but MAC didn't recognize it

Tags: python

I installed python 3.2 edition, but when I opened wingIDE, my MAC still only show the old edition phthon 2.6.1. I tried to use "configure python"-enter python3.2 in "python executable", then found nothing changed, python 2.6.1 still appeared in wingIDE. Any suggestion?

---

I just tried to launch WINGIDE again and this time it indicates the python 3.2, the newest edition i installed. hmmmm, funny, i didn't change anything and it recognized it now! But when i use terminal, it still only recognize python 2.6.

Comment: "Mac" is not an acronym, BTW. (BTW is!)

Answer (score 1):

Is python3.2 in your PATH? Try typing "python3.2" at the command line and see if that works. Where is python3.2 located? It's probably /usr/bin/python3.2 Try using that in WingIDE and see if that works.

Comment: i installed python 3.2 and then drag it to application folder, so i enter user/flora/application/python3.2, it said it is not in the path, seems the MAC couldn't find where the new edition is.....

Comment: btw, i tried the path you put there, and it still said it is not in the path

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the version of OSX you are running. I did a custom install of python 2.7 on my machine running 10.6.7 and had to modify ~/.bash_profile with the following line:

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"

You may want to check the directory /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions and see what the full path is to your 3.2 install. You could then modify the PATH variable in your ~/.bash_profile like this:

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/YOUR_VERSION_NUM/bin:${PATH}"

Comment: when i check my .bash_profile i have PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:${PATH}" export PATH but it still wont invoke python 3.3 from the command line, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

trying to fix wing myself, but if you want to just execute it via commandline...

in terminal:
python3.2 ./filename.py

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the "python" shortcut doesn't exist in "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin", which is the newly created binary location.
Create a soft link to "python" as a work around. 
"ln -s python python3.4". 
Also, make sure that your .bash_profile has an entry for /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin directory.
Verify with "Python -V"