# Using newest version of Python (3.2) on Mac (Snow Leapard)?

Tags: python

I downloaded the .dmg file from Python and ran the script in the folder called Python 3.2. However, after running the command file, I restarted the terminal and ran python again, and it is still running on the earlier version.

```
Python 2.4.6 (#1, Dec  1 2011, 04:16:52)
```

How can I make version 3.2 the default?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the python 3.2 to your PATH (I think the default .dmg installation location is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2), or you can add a symlink to it in your /usr/bin directory.

[python 3.2 installed, but MAC didn't recognize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628225/python-3-2-installed-but-mac-didnt-recognize-it-ask-help)

http://ask.metafilter.com/192685/How-can-I-install-Python-32-along-side-my-current-Python-27-installation-on-Mac-OS-1067

Comment: I added python 3.2 to my path but typing 'python' in the terminal still runs the old version. However, I am able to run the new version by typing 'python3.2'. How can i make that the default?

Comment: Python 3 should always been invoked as "python3". "python" should be Python 2. (see PEP 394)